# How to parse json values from API response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to parse json response from an API.

```
response = requests.post('https://analysis.lastline.com/analysis/get_completed', files=files)

my = response.json()
print my
```

**Output:**

```
{u'data': {u'tasks': [], u'more_results_available': 0, u'after': u'2018-03-18 22:00:20', u'before': u'2018-03-18 17:00:22'}, u'success': 1}
```

Here `my` is a dictionary. Now I want to get values against the keys.

I have tried this:

```
print my['tasks']
```

It gives me `KeyError`.

Comment: what does `print my['data']` give you?

Comment: try print my['data']['tasks']

Comment: @DanO I don't know how I missed that. Guess its pretty late for me to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested dictionary.
To access value against 'task' key, you should write like this:

```
print my['data']['tasks']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need use the `data` key to access `tasks`

**Ex:**

```
d = {u'data': {u'tasks': [], u'more_results_available': 0, u'after': u'2018-03-18 22:00:20', u'before': u'2018-03-18 17:00:22'}, u'success': 1}
print(d["data"]["tasks"])
print(d["data"]["after"])
```

**Output:**

```
[]
2018-03-18 22:00:20
```